# finding limit of the rational function when direct substitution is not possible?

Tags: limits

In the assignment we received in university we were asked to find limits of set of functions using either multiplication by some conjugate, refactoring, direct substitution, or squeeze theorem.

The particular example below seems puzzling:
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 6} \frac{\sqrt{x^{2} + x - 2} - \sqrt{x^{2} + 4}}{x - 6}$

At first i tried to multiply using numerator divided by itself or $\frac{\sqrt{x^{2} + x - 2} + \sqrt{x^{2} + 4}}{\sqrt{x^{2} + x - 2} + \sqrt{x^{2} + 4}}$ as conjugate but after simplification it still leads to division by zero.
I tried to solve the equation in $\sqrt{x^{2} + x - 2}$, but because the discriminant is not a finite fraction, that seem to be useless.

I thought that I can apply squeeze theorem but because the issue is in the denominator i cant just add and sub a constant as it will still result in the undefined value - and im not sure if other ways exist to create functions which are guaranteed to always yield lesser or greater values.

P.S. I see that second squared root has a sum of two squares inside, but if i dont think there is any way i can simplify it nontheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+x-2}$ and let $g(x)=\sqrt{x^2+4}$. Then\begin{align}\lim_{x\to6}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x-2}-\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x-6}&=\lim_{x\to6}\left(\frac{f(x)-40}{x-6}-\frac{g(x)-40}{x-6}\right)\\&=\lim_{x\to6}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(6)}{x-6}-\frac{g(x)-g(6)}{x-6}\right)\\&=f'(6)-g'(6)\\&=\frac1{4\sqrt{10}}.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for that answer, however could you clarify what is the rule you used in the first line of your conversion, where did offset of 40 came from?

Comment: It comes from the fact that $\sqrt{6^2+6-2}=\sqrt{6^2+4}=40$.

Comment: Could you perhaps mention the name of the process/technique you used so i can do further research? A lot is unclear to me, like for example how the limit of a difference maps to a difference of derivatives.

Comment: nvm, i found a resource which explains the connection - thanks you very much

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{\sqrt{x^{2} + x - 2} - \sqrt{x^{2} + 4}}{x - 6}=\frac{x-6}{(x-6)\left(\sqrt{x^{2} + x - 2} + \sqrt{x^{2} + 4}\right)}=$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt{x^{2} + x - 2} + \sqrt{x^{2} + 4}}\xrightarrow[x\to6]{}\frac1{\sqrt{40}+\sqrt{40}}=\frac1{4\sqrt{10}}$$

Comment: $2\sqrt{40}=4\sqrt{10}\ne8\sqrt5$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, good catch.